# How do I view the permissions of a file w/o using ls -l?

Tags: bash, unix

I just want to check the permissions of a single file w/o having to look through all of the files in the current directory.

Comment: You don't have to look through all of the files using `ls -l`. Try `ls -l FILENAME` to show only the file info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ls` with a single file: `ls -l filename`. Alternatively, you can use the `stat` command.

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways,

1. pass the file to `ls -l <filename>`
2. use `stat` eg `stat file` or use its options for permission format
3. use a programming language with `stat` like capability, eg Ruby

   $ ruby -e 'puts sprintf( "%o" , File.stat("file").mode )'